# WPF GroupBox hide/show with an expander button?

Tags: wpf, expander

Is there a control like `System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox` that can hide its contents and show only the name and an expander button?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) control.